# Silverlight infragistics remove styling on combobox when it is disabled

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, xaml, combobox, infragistics

Im having real trouble removing the styling on infragistics combobox (NetAdvantage 2012.2) under silverlight.  In its current state its barely visible with the opacity set down which makes the text light grey.  See the difference between a combobox and a regular textbox below.

Every styling change I make just does not effect the opacity on the combobox when it is disabled.

[image: comboboxdisabled]

below is the styling im trying to set at the moment.  I have tried a hundred different combos of code but this where im trying to make the changes.  I have changed the opacity on disabled to 0 hoping that would remove whatever item sits over the top of combobox.  Please let me know if im way off course here.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <System:Double>1</System:Double>
                                            </SplineDoubleKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </SplineDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into your issue and I can suggest you handle the XamComboEditor’s Loaded event and get the Border and the Rectangle that are responsible for the blurring of the text and set their Opacity to 0. Also there is a duplicate post at the Infragistics' forum, where a sample is uploaded:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/83793.aspx

In the future I can suggest you post your questions related to Infragistics controls there, becasue you will get an answer from an Infragistics expert.